# Sample of Android In-App Purchase receipt(response)

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I was searching for sample of response returned by google billing library and I did not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google returns

1: Response Code: Value is 0 if the purchase was successful, error otherwise.

2: Signature

3: Purchase data subscription contains `autoRenewing` property while managed product does not.

**UPDATE:** Android billing library's new version includes acknowledged property. I don't have new response for the product at hand.

```
Subscription:{
    "orderId":"GPA.2023-9153-0180-49403",
    "packageName":"com.package.name",
    "productId":"subscription.name.sku",
    "purchaseTime":1565763897962,
    "purchaseState":0,
    "purchaseToken":"kkoohioagkpieamagedjoiji.AO-J1Owj3YPtGxM9YOBSCywUo07BwcX79dAS24w7DvvxVi-gEzsXeRvkY5NGETBH8oDUaWc0oF4M8K3EiJ2v9JUfoGzxPazO51qpksIXGOkVPHI0DVJE3FzOdDd7bqbAIPVLFUo7u6SzdN1nRUlg9xoakvzqY8Kwow",
    "autoRenewing":true,
    "acknowledged":false
  }
```

The old response:

```
Subscription:
{
        "orderId":"string",
        "packageName":"string",
        "productId":"string",
        "purchaseTime":1423956863083,
        "purchaseState":0,
        "purchaseToken":"apafgjjemjhnoiadmmpffiil.AO-J1OySPl3pYGk4JliUkLj_Fro7FvGWiArPP0R1imx49HOmnJ4MroJNbSwkLk1WfYJmp_8g5ek5C9AAIjG_6GhC03-X0QMwfyc4epN_ZdkZqlxIKj0V5m6QQZDRhLW-8smEQ5R_USG4dtq6JTsK9UoxMO2YFXziGQ",
        "autoRenewing":true
}

Products:
{
    "orderId":"GPA.6027-7343-7915-33484",
    "packageName":"com.app.package.name",
    "productId":"quotation.1",
    "purchaseTime":1523956202686,
    "purchaseState":0,
    "purchaseToken":"kjcjjlmljnbifnlpcobchldi.AO-J1OyD96lBh3dYpPpf3yW3H4EzH_2XXFjNjL3jrVf-oPk-T7ZQvf-DF1Zd0LFtzPBn8hqdL_2ML6AXLgzBRkDcFAljIbv4Ck0ARxz-L4LPXAFgQvHGIn4Of00msbbkiI2ENpNKBgd6_MlxT7oTaMU3ltQmld7X2A"
}
```

Comment: Is it "autoRenew" or "autoRenewing" ?

Comment: As you can see in the sample it is "autoRenewing"

Comment: OK, thanks, I asked because in point 3 it's written "autoRenew"

Comment: @KishanVaishnav what is the "acknowledged":false used for?!

Comment: @KishanVaishnav lastly, how do you get the json object from within the app in Java?

Comment: I am not an Android Developer but I believe it is returned when the Flow is complete. There is a method which is called when the subscription is successful.

Comment: @Learn2Code  In the new version the app has to acknowledge the purchase after it is complete. The "acknowledged":false indicates whether the app has called that method or not.